# Displaying running console program data outputs in my to my visual studio application page

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, visual-studio

How can I show on my visual studio application page, a running program data outputs in console.

Comment: In Visual Studio there is a View called "Output"... This shows all the output you are printing using "Console.WriteLine or Debug.WriteLine. Did you try that already?

Comment: I don't want to write to the console. I want to read from the output of console of third application running at the console. ex: pinging an IP address results in my visual studio app.

Answer (score 1):

Okay based on your comment i think you want to execute a console program and redirect it´s output to your visual studio output Window? 
The following example is in C#

```cs
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/c ping www.google.de",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, //to hide the cmd window
    RedirectStandardOutput = true, //needed to redirect the output
    UseShellExecute = false
};

var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = processStartInfo
};

if (process.Start())
{
    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
         var outputLine = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
         if(outputLine != null)
             Debug.WriteLine(outputLine);
    }
}
```

Not that there is also the possibility to use events for that using 
`process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;` but this event is only raised when a full line is printed to stdout. If the application is writing to a buffer and not calling `Console.Out.Flush();` explicitly. The Ping example won´t work using the event method, so i choosed the synchronous read.

If you wan´t to know more about the event driven way, take a look here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx)